# Cannot compile RtMidi VS community 2015

Tags: c++, midi, lnk2001

I am following the basic tutorial on https://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtmidi/ and I cannot seem to make it past the first step in "Getting Started."

Originally I was only getting two errors, one of which was a "LNK2019 - unresolved external symbol" error, which I fixed by linking rtmidi.lib and rtmidid.lib

Now I have a huge block of errors that I can't make any sense of

```
rtmidi.lib(RtMidi.obj) : MSIL .netmodule or module compiled with /GL found; restarting link with /LTCG; add /LTCG to the link command line to improve linker performance
LINK : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/INCREMENTAL' due to '/LTCG' specification
RTMIDI_test.obj : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to '/OPT:LBR' specification
rtmidi.lib(RtMidi.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in RTMIDI_test.obj
rtmidi.lib(RtMidi.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in RTMIDI_test.obj
LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
rtmidi.lib(RtMidi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__midiInUnprepareHeader@12
rtmidi.lib(RtMidi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__midiInOpen@20
rtmidi.lib(RtMidi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__midiOutGetDevCapsW@12
rtmidi.lib(RtMidi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__midiOutPrepareHeader@12
rtmidi.lib(RtMidi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__midiOutOpen@20
rtmidi.lib(RtMidi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__midiInReset@4
rtmidi.lib(RtMidi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__midiInPrepareHeader@12
rtmidi.lib(RtMidi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__midiOutUnprepareHeader@12
rtmidi.lib(RtMidi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__midiInGetDevCapsW@12
rtmidi.lib(RtMidi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__midiInStart@4
rtmidi.lib(RtMidi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__midiInClose@4
rtmidi.lib(RtMidi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__midiInAddBuffer@12
rtmidi.lib(RtMidi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__midiInGetNumDevs@0
rtmidi.lib(RtMidi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__midiOutShortMsg@8
rtmidi.lib(RtMidi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__midiOutGetNumDevs@0
rtmidi.lib(RtMidi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__midiOutLongMsg@12
rtmidi.lib(RtMidi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__midiOutClose@4
rtmidi.lib(RtMidi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__midiInStop@4
rtmidi.lib(RtMidi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__midiOutReset@4
C:\Users\Zach\Desktop\RTMIDI_test\Debug\RTMIDI_test.exe : fatal error     LNK1120: 19 unresolved externals
```

Obviously on lines 7-25 it's looking for a library or something that doesn't exist, but gives no hints as to what it is. The rest however, I can't even begin to figure out. Any Ideas?

I read somewhere else to change the project option to "Release" Which does get rid of the above messages, but instead replaces them with

```
RTMIDI_test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall RtMidiIn::RtMidiIn(enum RtMidi::Api,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,unsigned int)" (??0RtMidiIn@@QAE@W4Api@RtMidi@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@I@Z)
C:\Users\Zach\Desktop\RTMIDI_test\Release\RTMIDI_test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the link errors tell you what you need to do to fix them (at least in combination with a bit of googling)

```
rtmidi.lib(RtMidi.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in RTMIDI_test.obj
rtmidi.lib(RtMidi.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in RTMIDI_test.obj
```

So `RTMIDI_test.cpp` has been compiled with a different value for `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL` than in `rtmidi.lib`.  The next line says that you are trying to link your debug project with a release build of `rtmidi.lib`. You should change this to link against the debug version instead which should remove some or all of the other warnings and errors.

```
rtmidi.lib(RtMidi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__midiInUnprepareHeader@12
```

`midiInUnprepareHeader` and the other `midiIn*` functions live in `winmm.lib` (see the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd798464%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), so you also need to link against that.

Comment: Ok, so with RtMidi you have to compile the .lib files yourself by using the included visual studio project. rtmidi.lib is the release version, and rtmidid.lib is the debug version (i was wondering what that "d" at the end meant).

I will try and see if I can only use the debug version

Comment: So linking winmm.lib fixed all of the LNK2001 errors, and apparently I had both the debug and release versions of the library linked at the same time. I unlinked the release version and it worked. Thank you for your help! I will continue with the tutorial and hope it fixed the problem